# How is the elasticity of labor calculated, with only hours worked, taxed income and effective tax rate in a progressive tax system?

Tags: macroeconomics

I am trying to determine the elasticity of labor in a local labor market, and statistics are gathered regularly, but there are what seems to be confounding variables and systematic issues.

I have anual statistics on the number of hours worked in the market, what the taxable income was, and the effective tax rate. The tax rate is the issue.

The tax rate here, on the Faroe Islands, is progressive, going from 15% after the first 60k, up to 55% at the top of the scale. This means the effective tax rate will go up when people work more hours, and down when there isn't enough work to go around. This will make the elasticity negative, which would be an error in the models I use.

I have studied macroeconomics before, and I am working on calculating dead-weight losses in the labor market (not as a job, just for myself), and I am going to use elasticity of labor to calculate the deadweight loss. However, I don't know which model I should use in this case.

Help will be appreciated.